# Read Iterations from TFS 2013 via REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint, tfs

When i navigate to `myTFSInstance/myProject/_admin/_iterations` i get a page listing the project iterations... what i would like to do is to read it via REST API...

I've managed to get to MS docs about the REST API and:

- `myTFSInstance/myProject/_api/lists/getbytitle('iterations')/items`
  Returns 404
- `myTFSInstance/myProject/_api/lists/getbytitle('_iterations')/items`
  Also Returns 404

In the end what i'm trying to accomplish is to get a Sharepoint 2010 XML webpart to render the list using XSL...

What else should I try?

Comment: The new Rest API isn't available on TFS 2013 RTM. The REST APi was introduced in TFS 2013 Update 2,

Comment: @jessehouwing I understand that the new one is quite "better", but isn't this possible in the old one? i mean, read all list's items is quite basic don't you agree?

Comment: Most of the Rest API's only shipped with TFS 2013 update 2. Before that there was only REST support on Visual Studio Online and very few REST API's for Team Rooms.